# ALerting in Riemann?

Tags: clojure, monitoring, logstash, riemann

I am using ELK (logstash, ES, Kibana) stack for log analysis and Riemann for alerting. I have logs in which users is one of the fields parsed by logstash and I send the events to riemann from riemann output plugin.

Logstash parses logs and user is one of the field. Eg: logs parsed

```
Timestamp              user     command-name
 2014-06-07...         root      sh ./scripts/abc.sh
 2014-06-08...         sid       sh ./scripts/xyz.sh
 2014-06-08...         abc       sh ./scripts/xyz.sh
 2014-06-09...         root      sh ./scripts/xyz.sh
```

**Logstash:**

```
riemann {
    riemann_event => {
        "service"     => "logins"
        "unique_user" => "%{user}"
    }
}
```

So users values will be like: root, sid, abc, root, sid, def, etc....

So I split stream by user i.e one stream for each unique user. Now, I want to alert when number of unique users count go more than 3. I wrote the following but it's **not** achieving my purpose.

**Riemann:**

```
(streams

 (where (service "logins")
  (by :unique_user
    (moving-time-window 3600 
     (smap (fn [events]
      (let
        [users (count events)]
         (if (> users 3)
          (email "abc@gmail.com")       
     ))))))))
```

I am new to Riemann and clojure. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`email` returns a stream. Therefore, for it to work, you must either use it as a stream, by passing it as a parameter to another stream, or use `call-rescue` to send an event to it directly. Additionally, streams that are meant to receive events from multiple sources (such as your alert destination) should be created once, and stored in a variable for re-use.

First approach, using only abstract streams:

```
(let [alert (email "abc@gmail.com")]
  (streams
    (where (service "logins")
      (by :unique_user
        (moving-time-window 3600
          (smap folds/count
            (where (> metric 3) alert)))))))
```

Second approach, using `call-rescue`:

```
(let [alert (email "abc@gmail.com")]
  (streams
    (where (service "logins")
      (by :unique_user
        (moving-time-window 3600
          (fn [events]
            (when (> (count events) 3)
              (call-rescue (last events) alert))))))))
```